# Mule Fundamentals Video Not Working for Me

Tags: mule, windows-10

I've followed the Mule Fundamentals video successfully using a Macbook Pro. I have Windows 10 now and I'm doing the same thing but in this case, the `url/?language=French` does not work i.e. the query param `language=` shows Spanish in logger and in every case the message flow runs through the `Variable` component for the Spanish default.

I have checked and double-checked every component but it's like `message.inboundProperties` does not recognize the set Variable `Language` in the variable component `#[message.inboundProperties['language']]`.

In every case of `language=anything`, the `language=Spanish` (default) and the default payload is `"Hola! Como esa"`

Here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="hellomuleFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <expression-filter expression="#[message.payload != '/favicon.ico']" doc:name="Expression" />
        <set-variable variableName="Language" value="#[message.inboundProperties['language']]" doc:name="Set Language Variable"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars['language']=='Japanese']">
                <set-payload value="Konichiwa" doc:name="Respond in Japanese"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[flowVars['language']=='French']">
                <set-payload value="Bonjour" doc:name="Respond in French"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-variable variableName="language" value="Zulu" doc:name="Set Language"/>
                <set-payload value="Hola" doc:name="Respond in Spanish"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="The response &quot;#[message.payload]&quot; means Hello in #[flowVars['language']]"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Please share your entire mule xml

Answer (score 0):

Make a correction in setting the variable value. You are trying to read the query parameter values from the header.Change the MEL expression as follows while setting the variable value. Change the value to "#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.language]" in setting the variable

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks Suda. I think the video is incorrect or the inboundProperties is sufficient for Mac but not for WIndows 10. When I added http.query.params'.language. That fixed it. (Windows 10 different?)